Phase of two signals by correlation slightly off, scipy signal.correlate
I want to get the phase shift of two signals via the correlation function. In general I set up a sine with frequency f0 and a 2nd sine (with noise) and a given phase phase_deg. I correlate both signals via scipy signal.correlate, find the maximum of the correlation function and recalculate the phase from the time lags.
In principle it works, while I seem to always be slightly off (underestimating) the original phase. For no noise, the original and recovered phase should be identical. I might have a shifted or wrong index somewhere, but I can't find the problem.
The code I use is below:
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()


noise_pct = 0. 
f0 = 10000 #Hz

nsamples = int(1e3) #samples by osci
dt = 1e-6 #dt per sample
times = np.arange(nsamples) * dt
assert 1/dt > (2*f0), "Shannon!"

sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * times)
phase_deg = 66
phase_rad = np.deg2rad(phase_deg) # or phase_deg * np.pi / 180.
phaselag = phase_deg / (360 * f0) / dt #(phase lag in s)
sig_noise = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * times - phase_rad) + rng.standard_normal(len(sig)) * noise_pct

print('Original phase was {} deg with a delay of {} s'.format(phase_deg, phaselag*dt))

#normalized correlation of two signals
corr = signal.correlate(sig_noise, sig)
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(sig), len(sig_noise))
corr /= np.max(corr)


#plot both signals and the crosscorrelation
show_n_periods = 10

fig, (ax_orig, ax_corr) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax_orig.set_xlim(0, show_n_periods/f0)
ax_orig.plot(times,sig_noise)
ax_orig.plot(times,sig)
ax_orig.grid()
ax_orig.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_orig.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
ax_orig.set_title('signals to correlate')
ax_orig.set_xlabel('t (s)')
#
ax_corr.plot(lags*dt, corr)
ax_corr.set_title('cross-correlated signal')
ax_corr.set_xlabel('phase lag (s)')
ax_corr.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
ax_corr.set_xlim(-show_n_periods/f0, show_n_periods/f0)
ax_corr.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_corr.grid()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#get the lag and phase from the maximum of the correlation function
print('The estimated phase by cross-correlation is {} deg'.format(lags[np.argmax(corr)] * 360 * f0 * dt))

The output is Original phase was 66 deg with a delay of 1.8333333333333333e-05 s The estimated phase by cross-correlation is 64.8 deg. So I am off quite a bit from the original 66deg.


So, you have a 10000 Hz signal, sampled at 1MHz, right? That is 100 samples per entire period. Or 100 samples for 360 degrees. Is it really surprising that you don't get a precision better than 3.6° ?

Said otherwise, is there a reason to use an index-based lag computing method to estimate just a phase?  That is both slow and inaccurate. When Shannon, that you've mentioned in your code, tells precisely that you don't really need to have "index accuracy" to know what happens (as long as your assert is true)

@chrslg thank you, indeed that’s the limitation. In reality the sample rate is at 62.5MHz for signals up to 100kHz, so slightly more „accurate“.
To your 2nd comment. What other method do you have in mind? Correlation/covariance where the first things coming to my mind to automatically get the relative phase of two noisy signals.

Well, the difficulty with this kind of conversation, is that I can't help thinking "one of us is naive" :D. Because what I have in mind is so simple, that it is either surprising that someone who, apparently, works in this field didn't try. But maybe the reason is that it is so simple, that only someone that doesn't work in this field (me. I teach maths, but know nothing on signal) could ignore the zillions reason why it doesn't work in real life.

(rest of comments removed and put in an answer. It was getting too long for comments)

Answering in comment is a bit too tedious. So I put that in an answer (even tho I am still not sure whether the reason why you didn't use that in the first place is because you, surprisingly, didn't know about that, or if it is me that, less surprisingly, since I know nothing about signal processing, is naive to even think that this works in real life).
So, what I have in mind with my second comment was to define,
sigc = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * times)
just after the similar your
sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * times)
you already have
And then phase is
np.arctan((sig_noise@sigc) / (sig_noise@sig))
Since sig@sigc is 0 (to the numerical error). Because
∫ sin(2πft)cos(2πft)dt is 0 (if the integration interval [a,b] includes an integer number of periods. That is if 2πf(b-a) is a factor of 2π. That is your case: f=10000Hz, and integration interval is [0, 10⁻³ s], so 10 periods.
And sig@sig is ½ × 1000 (∫sin(ωt)sin(ωt)dt = ½(b-a) )
So for a dephased signal
u(t) = sin(ωt+φ) = cos(φ)sin(ωt) + sin(φ)cos(ωt)
you have <u,sin>=½cos(φ)×10⁻³, and <u,cos>=½sin(φ)×10⁻³ (10⁻³ being the width of integration interval. So 1000×10⁻⁶ in your case).
u@sig and u@sigc are therefore also that (times a constant, that is the inverse of integration step), since it is, to that constant factor, the numerical integration of u(t)×sig(t) and u(t)xsigc(t).
So, detail doesn't matter. Point is both sig@u and sigc@u are the same constant, times cos(φ) for the first, and sin(φ) for the second.
So (sigc@u)/(sig@u) is tan(φ). Hence the formula (u is here what you called sig_noise)
That advantage of that compared to a "index-based" solution, is that the width of the sample doesn't really matter. As long as sample size respect Shannon theorem (and even that, is too much if your signal is just a dephased sin: Shannon theorem is supposing that the signal is a linear combination of all frequencies under half the period, with all phase. If you know that your signal is Asin(ωt+φ), with ω known, then, theoretically, 2 values are enough to know A and φ)
So, sampling interval is almost irrelevant when it comes to accuracy. It the the "heights" of the signal that contain the information, not the position of its max.
I say "almost", because you can't expect to solve the exact equation "Asin(ωt+φ)=u(t)" (unless your signal, is, as your example fabricated, and withnout noise). So you need a least square estimation (since the base of sin and cos are orthogonal, it is just a simple projection, done by my sig@u and sigc@u). And in such a least square/orthogonal projection, the more points you have, the better.
Plus, the noise is supposed to be orthogonal to any sin(ωt+φ). But only in the long run, when its correlation, theoretically 0, computed on a number of samples big enough is practically 0). So, the more noise you have, the more points you need.
But the need for samples has nothing to do with a "argmax", and a "horizontal" resolution.
To make an analogy, it is a bit like you were trying to find a parabola y=ax²+bx+c for a set of (xᵢ,yᵢ) points.
My method would be to compute orthogonal projection of columns (y₁,y₂,...,yₙ) on the subspace generated by columns (x₁²,x₂²,...,xₙ²), (x₁,x₂,...,xₙ), (1,1,...,1).
Your would be to say "let's find for which xᵢ, yᵢ is either maximal or minimal, that gives us value of -b/2a"... which is highly dependent on the fact that you have enough xᵢ to be sure that the minimum or maximum one is not far to -b/2a.
You don't need to have a sample precisely at the minimum of a parabola to be able to guess its parameters. 3 points are enough. And even if those points are unsure because of noise, then the more points you have, the better. But still, you don't need to have one at the minimum or maximum.
So, again, I don't know if I am stating something that is not only obvious, but also obviously not applicable.
But I have the feeling (again, without any knowledge in signal processing) that that correlation method is something you would do for a non periodic signal. When the only method is to test all possible phase, and select the best (which is what you implicitly do, even I bet that scipy don't litteraly compute all phase, and rely on some Fourier transform/convolution)
When you know that your signal is a sinus plus a noise, just plain projection should be enough
Since this is now a full answer, not a bunch of comment, I can post my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()


noise_pct = 0. 
f0 = 10000 #Hz

nsamples = int(1e3) #samples by osci
dt = 1e-6 #dt per sample
times = np.arange(nsamples) * dt
assert 1/dt > (2*f0), "Shannon!"

sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * times)
sigc = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * times)
phase_deg = 66
phase_rad = np.deg2rad(phase_deg) # or phase_deg * np.pi / 180.
phaselag = phase_deg / (360 * f0) / dt #(phase lag in s)
sig_noise = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f0 * times - phase_rad) + rng.standard_normal(len(sig)) * noise_pct

print('Original phase was {} deg with a delay of {} s'.format(phase_deg, phaselag*dt))

#normalized correlation of two signals
corr = signal.correlate(sig_noise, sig)
lags = signal.correlation_lags(len(sig), len(sig_noise))
corr /= np.max(corr)


#plot both signals and the crosscorrelation
show_n_periods = 10

fig, (ax_orig, ax_corr) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 6))
ax_orig.set_xlim(0, show_n_periods/f0)
ax_orig.plot(times,sig_noise)
ax_orig.plot(times,sig)
ax_orig.grid()
ax_orig.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_orig.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
ax_orig.set_title('signals to correlate')
ax_orig.set_xlabel('t (s)')
#
ax_corr.plot(lags*dt, corr)
ax_corr.set_title('cross-correlated signal')
ax_corr.set_xlabel('phase lag (s)')
ax_corr.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(0,0))
ax_corr.set_xlim(-show_n_periods/f0, show_n_periods/f0)
ax_corr.margins(0, 0.1)
ax_corr.grid()
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

#get the lag and phase from the maximum of the correlation function
print('The estimated phase by cross-correlation is {} deg'.format(lags[np.argmax(corr)] * 360 * f0 * dt))
print('My estimate', -180/np.pi*np.arctan((sig_noise@sigc) / (sig_noise@sig)))

(This is just your code, with 2 extra lines: the one defining sigc, and the last one. But that last line rely on nothing but the previous definition of sig, sigc and sig_noise)
Timing-wise, the advantage is obvious too. My computation takes 10μs on my machine, vs 500 μs for yours (which is normal, and shows how efficient scipy is: what you compute is the equivalent of 500 times my computation. So, it is miraculous that it is "only" 50 times slower. Just, you don't need to compute all that).
And as you can see, result is "perfect". On this "0 noise" example, it shows "My estimate 65.99999999999997"
Which is normal. That is using least-square to solve an exact "Asin(ωtᵢ+φ) = u(tᵢ)" problem, for which, theoretically, you can have an exact answer with just two tᵢ
